# Issue while running php code

Tags: php, error-handling

When I installed this script i got this error [image: error] 
which has this line of congig.php file[image: line]

Can you help me to solve the error

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $host       =   "localhost"; // your mysql server address
    $user       =   "root"; // your mysql username
    $pass       =   ""; // your mysql password
    $tablename  =   "ses"; // your mysql table

    session_start();
    $data = null;
    if(!(@mysql_connect("$host","$user","$pass") && @mysql_select_db("$tablename"))) {
        ?>
        <html>
        MSQL ERROR
        <?
        exit;
    }

    include_once 'functions.php';
    require_once "includes/pluggable.php";
    foreach( glob("plugins/*/index.php")  as $plugin) {  
      require_once($plugin);  
    }  

    hook_action('initialize');

    $site = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings"));
    ?>
```

Comment: You probably forgot to close a curly bracket (`{`).

Comment: i had updated question.pls have a look

Comment: Post your entire config.php file.

Comment: mysql_connect("$host","$user","$pass") quotes????

Comment: `config.php` doesn't influence anything. The inclusion is done at runtime but there is no run time here. This code doesn't run because it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Use `pdo` class for connecting database

Comment: Your php support short-tags? short-tags (`<?`) it is only available if enabled using the `short_open_tag` php.ini configuration file directive and **IT'S DEPRECATED**. Try to replace `<?` with `<?php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you gots this:

```
     ?>
    <html>
    MSQL ERROR
    <?
    exit;
```

You needs this:

```
     ?>
    <html>
    MSQL ERROR
    <?php
    exit;
```

`<?` is not a valid opening tag unless you have short_open_tag enabled in your php.ini

Comment: This is probably the solution of the issue but if you don't explain why, the op won't learn very much from it.

Comment: does that create difference ? OMG i had seen it first time

Comment: It only matters if OP doesn't have short-tags enabled. If he does, you can use `<?` too.

Comment: @KingsAdam if your PHP interpreter has the `php.ini` setting [`short_open_tags = 0`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) then `<?` is not an opening tag for PHP.

Comment: I think the king has left the building.